# SQL Server Management Studio - find stored procedure by name over multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have recently joined a software project that has approximately 20-40 databases.

Each database has at least 200 stored procedures, some of them have many more, so it is very slow for me to search for a particular procedure manually.

I know that there is a stored procedure which I need to look at to fix a bug, **somewhere** in the entire project, it is called `XYZ_procedure`

How do I search for this procedure over all of my databases in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL to check procedure over all of databases in SQL Server Management Studio

```
USE MASTER
GO
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @strt INT,@End INT,@Database NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT * INTO #T FROM Sys.databases WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE database_id>4 
ORDER BY 1

SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()OVER (ORDER BY database_Id)Db_Id,* INTO #TT FROM #T
SET @strt=1
SELECT @End=Max(Db_ID)FROM #tt

WHILE @strt<=@END
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)
         SELECT @Database=NAME FROM #TT WHERE Db_ID=@strt

        Set @string='  Select '''+@Database+'''db_Name,* from '+@Database+'.sys.objects 
          WHERE Name=''XYZ_procedure'''

          SET @strt=@strt+1
          PRINT @string
          EXEC(@string)
     END

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it right. You need a way to filter the procedures by name in SSMS. You can refer the following link :

[Find Using Filter Settings In Object Explorer](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/search-find-stored-procedure)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use the undocumented stored procedure `sp_MSForeachdb` which executes a command for each database:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 
'
USE ?
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name = ''XYZ_procedure''
    )
    SELECT DB_NAME();
'
```